# WebView DefaultBackgroundColor Transparent does not render to WebViewBrush

Tags: c#, uwp, inkcanvas

I have a transparent background webview that occasionally I need to interact over (for inking). When I switch to the webviewbrush the webviewbrush renders the transparency as black. I am wondering how to get render transparent:
C# Code:

```
private void MyInkToolbar_ActiveToolChanged(InkToolbar toolbar, object sender)
        {
            if (myInkToolbar.ActiveTool == objectSelect)
            {
                textCanvas.IsHitTestVisible = true;
                testTiny.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                testTinyOverlay.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            }
            else
            {
                if (textCanvas.IsHitTestVisible == true)
                {
                    testTinyOverlay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    CaptureWebView();
                    testTiny.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    textCanvas.IsHitTestVisible = false;
                }
            }
        }
        private void CaptureWebView()
        {
            WebViewBrush b = new WebViewBrush();
            b.SetSource(testTiny);
            b.Redraw();
            testTinyOverlay.Fill = b;
        }
```

Xaml Code:

```
<Canvas x:Name="textCanvas">
                        <Grid Name="testTinyGrid" Width="200" Height="200" Background="Transparent">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="testTinyOverlay" Fill="Transparent"/>
                            <WebView x:Name="testTiny" DefaultBackgroundColor="Transparent" Source="ms-appx-web:///HTML/TinyEditor.html"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Canvas>
```

[Webview Render Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3mvB.png)

[WebViewBrush Render Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bWuh.png)

Answer (score 0):

`WebView.DefaultBackgroundColor` is an additional background, `DefaultBackgroundColor` is like paper, Html content is like painting. `WebViewBrush` is equivalent to taking a snapshot of the current WebView when rendering.

If `WebView.DefaultBackgroundColor` is **Transparent**, it means that the WebView itself has no background, but the background color is provided by the underlying elements (such as the page itself). This is not a visual problem, but the snapshot cannot extract any background pixels, which is caused by rendering `WebViewBrush` appears black, this represents an image with no background color.

According to this, the workaround is to set the `DefaultBackgroundColor` for WebView, which can be set to the same color as the page background (such as white) to maintain the same visual effect.

Thanks.